# Getting a SORT operator when number of rows being updated is above a threshold

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, azure-sql-database, performance-tuning

I'm working a table that has VARCHAR(18) as the PK.  I'm putting this here in case it's significant.

We have a SP that runs as part of an ETL that updates X rows each time.

I've noticed that when the number of rows reaches a certain threshold (the number is different in each env) then we get a SORT operator as well as NC indexes being updated too.

I've replicated this with the scripts below.  The threshold in this example is 3914 rows.

Here's the [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ3wdGvvn) without the NC indexes being updated and no SORT.

This is the [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1aGuzwD2) with the NC indexes being updated as well as the SORT.

Why am I getting the expensive SORT operator?  If the Eager Spools can be removed then that would be a bonus.

DDL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Target1
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Target1 (
    Id      VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK__Target1 PRIMARY KEY ,
    Active  BIT NULL , 
    Column1 VARCHAR(18) NULL ,
    Column2 VARCHAR(18) NULL 
) ;

CREATE INDEX IX__Target1__One ON dbo.Target1 (Active) INCLUDE (Column1, Column2);
GO
CREATE INDEX IX__Target1__Two ON dbo.Target1 (Column1, Column2, Active) ;
GO

WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)
    ,E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b)
    ,E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b)
    ,E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b)
    ,E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)
    ,E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a, E16 b)
    ,cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E32)
INSERT INTO dbo.Target1 (Id, Active, Column1, Column2)
SELECT  LEFT(REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', ''),18), 
        IIF(N.N % 2 = 0, 1, 0), 
        IIF(N.N % 2 <> 0, LEFT(NEWID(),18), NULL), 
        IIF(N.N % 2 = 0, LEFT(NEWID(),18), NULL)
FROM    cteTally    N 
WHERE   N.N <= 1000000 ;
```

Test Query

```
/*for info: this table is populated by the ETL*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Temp;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temp (Id VARCHAR (18) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO dbo.Temp (Id)
SELECT TOP 3914 Id FROM dbo.Target1 --increase to 3915 to get the SORT and NC index updates

/**/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IdsToDeactivate;
CREATE TABLE #IdsToDeactivate (Id VARCHAR (18) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #IdsToDeactivate (Id)
SELECT  S.Id 
FROM    dbo.Target1 S 
WHERE EXISTS(   SELECT  1/0
                FROM    dbo.Temp T 
                WHERE   T.Id=S.Id 
            ) ;


/*  Here when <= 3914 rows are updated I get no SORT and neither NC index is updated, just the clustered one
    but if the rows is >= 3915 then I get a SORT and both NC indexes are updated aswell as the clustered one*/
UPDATE  TGT 
SET     Active=0 
FROM    dbo.Target1         TGT
JOIN    #IdsToDeactivate    SRC ON SRC.Id= TGT.Id OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I've already included the query plans.

Comment: The most informative part of the dupe is this link https://web.archive.org/web/20151023181154/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/07/27/680518.aspx